# Are there procedures which are not stored procedures in SQL or SQL/PSM?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, procedure, sql-psm

Are there procedures which are not stored procedures in SQL or SQL/PSM?

Or are all the procedures in SQL or SQL/PSM all stored procedures?

I was worried if I am missing something, because in a general-purpose programming language, there is the concept of procedure but not stored procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably requires extended answer, but there are other object types other than a stored procedure such as functions, view, and triggers which each can contain procedural code.  "procedural code" not being a technical SQL term, but in concept each of these objects can have multiple lines of code of the type "do this, then do this, if this, else that" which conceptually is procedural code.  Typically a view *should* only have set based code, but it possible to have procedural code but usually would not be recommended.

Comment: "Are there procedures which are not stored procedures " I believe the  "stored" part means that the "procedure" is stored as text as part of the DataStructure ("schema") In that respect a function or view would identically be "stored".  a "non-Stored" proecedure would/could be any series of transactions and or queries that were run as commands, directly.

Comment: @AaronLS Thanks. Are all kinds of procedural code (stored procedure, functions, views and triggers) stored on database or DBMS, once created?

Comment: @DaniDev Thanks. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113934/are-all-kinds-of-procedural-code-stored-on-server-side-once-created-how-are-th

Comment: @AaronLS Thanks. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113934/are-all-kinds-of-procedural-code-stored-on-server-side-once-created-how-are-th

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of a "non-stored" procedure in SQL. The closest thing would probably just be a query, or collection of related queries, that you compose in your query window.