# Are all kinds of procedural code stored on server side, once created? How are they stored?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, rdbms

1. Are all kinds of procedural code (stored procedure, functions, views
   and triggers) stored on database or database management system
   server, once created, regardless of how they are created (for
   example, typing their definitions interactively in a command-line
   client of the database management system)? I am asking this because

   - in the command-line client of a RDBMS (such as postgresql, mysql, server sql), when typing a query statement, the query statement
     isn't stored any where.
   - in an interactive command-line REPL for a general purpose programming language, when typing the definition of a function or
     procedure, the function or procedure will not exist after closing
     the session of the REPL.
2. How are procedures, functions and triggers and views stored?

   Are they stored per table, per database or per database management
   system server?

   If they are stored per database, are they stored in a separate table 
   from the tables that store the actual data and are in the same database?  For example, in every database, besides those tables which store the actual data, is there a
   table which stores the stored procedures of the database, a table
   the functions of the database, a table the views of the database,
   and a table the triggers of the database?

   Similar questions if they are stored per table, or per database
   management system server.

Thanks.

Comment: In mysql procedures and functions are stored in information_schema.routines.

Comment: are they stored per server, database or table?

Comment: this is a pretty broad question to answer... short answer.. in mysql the producedures and functions are in information_schema.routines.. triggers are in information_schema.triggers.. views are in the information_schema.views.

Comment: You can read up on information_schema here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Although information about routines etc can be viewed in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, they're not really "stored in" those tables. Those are just views providing a (roughly) standards-compliant way of looking up the information, which is stored by MySQL wherever is convenient for their implementation.