# What does a procedure belong to?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures

In MySQL, I create a procedure under a database `test` which contains a table `CUSTOMERS1`:

```
mysql> use test;

mysql> delimiter //;

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM CUSTOMERS1;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```

If I want to look up the procedure, I have to do it as if the    procedure belongs to table `information_schema.routines` :

```
mysql> use information_schema;
Database changed

mysql> select * from routines where routine_name = "simpleproc";
```

If I want to call the procedure, I have to do it as if the procedure
   belongs to the database  `test` under which I created the procedure:

```
mysql> call test.simpleproc(@a);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I am a little confused about which the procedure belongs to in MySQL, the database  `test` under which I created the procedure, or table `information_schema.routines`?

Is it also a case in PostgreSQL? (I was wondering if the case is just for MySQL, not for standard SQL? PostgreSQL is the most faithful implementation of standard SQL.)

Note that I have asked a related question before: [Are all kinds of procedural code stored on server side, once created? How are they stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113934/are-all-kinds-of-procedural-code-stored-on-server-side-once-created-how-are-th)

Thanks.

Comment: It belongs to `test`.

Comment: Thanks. Then why can't I look it up from `test`, but in `table information_schema.routines`?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is special schema to store data about objects like tables/functions/views/indexes and so on.

Comment: postgres `select * from information_schema.routines where routine_name = 'simpleproc'` (can add `and specific_schema = 'test1' if you created in that schema). calling: `select test1.simpleproc()`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks. Can I look up the procedure from the database `test` to which it belongs, instead from `information_schema.routines`?

Comment: I guess the best way is to use some graphical tool. Just use object explorer and check what is inside `test` and `information_schema`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html Same for PostgreSQL. INFORMATION_SCHEMA contains **metadata** only.

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks. How is a procedure stored in its database? Is the procedure `simpproc` stored as a table under database `test`, or as a record of a table under database `test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not look up the routine in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` because it belongs there, but because the purpose of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is to show information about all items in the current database, regardless of "schema".

Note that the interpretation of what constitutes a "schema" varies between databases, but generally, the hierarchy is that an "instance", "server" or "cluster" contains several "databases", and a "database" contains several "schemas" (or "schemata", if you're fond of Latin plurals).

The special schema called `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is specified in the SQL standard, automatically exists in every database, and contains information about all information in that database. This is generally implemented as a set of views which format implementation-specific "system catalogues" into the format specified by the standard.

In MySQL, the concepts of "database" and "schema" are largely combined, so `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` appears as a database, with information on all other databases on the instance. [[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)]. Your routine belongs to the database `test`, and [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html) will show this in the `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` column.

You can access any of the views in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` without switching databases by qualifying their names. To filter objects to just the current database, you could use [the `database()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database), which returns the current database name. For instance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME;
```

In PostgreSQL, there is no communication between databases on a cluster, and every object belongs to a specific schema within a specific database. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a schema automatically present in all databases, and shows all objects within that database. [[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-schema.html)].

Comment: Thanks. Can I look up the procedure from the database `test` to which it belongs, instead from `information_schema.routines`?

Comment: Thanks. How is a procedure stored in its database? Is the procedure `simpproc` stored as a table under database `test`, or as a record of a table under database `test`?

Comment: @Tim At that point, you are getting into implementation details which I have no idea about, and which you really don't need to think about unless you're making modifications to the very core of MySQL. It could be stored as a separate file on disk, or a node in an XML file, if that's what the implementation needed. Probably, there's an internal table-like structure somewhere with a row describing the stored procedure, but the difference between "is stored as" and "is visible as" is not easy to dig past without examining MySQL's source code.

Comment: Thanks. In postgresql, "INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a schema visible in all databases, and shows all objects within that database". I wonder does different database have different INFORMATION_SCHEMA, or there is only one INFORMATION_SCHEMA which stores the info of all the databases and is shared by all the databases?

Comment: @Tim There is almost certainly nothing stored in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, in any database; it's a set of views, provided by the DBMS for user convenience, on top of implementation-specific details, which may or may not look anything like a normal database table. In PostgreSQL, you can't see anything outside the current database, so the views only show you information about the current database.

Comment: Thanks. I see the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`  are views. In PostgreSQL, is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` part of any database, i.e. does every database has its own `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: @Tim This is turning into a long discussion, not suited for this format, and I'm not sure how to explain any better than I have already, so I'm going to leave this here, because I believe I have answered the question on this page.